# Spring Boot component scan include only specific package

Tags: java, spring, dependency-injection, spring-boot, component-scan

I have two `Spring Boot` Projects lets call them `Foo` and `Bar`. `Bar` is included in `Foo` as a dependency. Now I want to include only a specific Package from `Bar` in the `Component Scan` of `Foo` (let's say: `com.example.bar.ctrl`). I know that you can exclude packages via `excludeFilters` but that would be much more effort and I'd need to maintain the `exclude filter-list` everytime I create a new package in `Bar`.
What is the best way to archive that behavior?

Comment: Is an include filter in the Foo project not enough?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would do it this way:

1) Foo package would have all beans under `com.example.foo` and also `@SpringBootApplication` main class would be in that package, so that it would scan all beans from `com.example.foo` package.

2) In bar package `com.example.bar.ctrl`, I would create `@Configuration` with `@ComponentScan` annotation without any attributes, so it would scan only `ctrl` package + subpackages.

3) I would `@Import` configuration class from point 2) into main class from point 1)

No explicit package needed for `@ComponentScan`'s `include` or `exclude` attribute.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the `@ComponentScan` annotation, then it has a `basePackages` attribute which take a `String[]` of the packages to scan.